# Is there code for door open direction

Tags: doors

I hired a contractor to finish my basement recently. Job already done.

But I think the bathroom door is installed at wrong direction.

The door is open toward outside instead of inside.

This cause safety concern, if my kid is running in the hallway, and the door is open, she may get hurt.

Is there any code about that I can use to argument with my contractor to ask him fix it?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/any-us-building-codes-about-a-door-opening-into-a-hallway-near-a-stairway?rq=1

Comment: @zpwang There is no code on the entry door itself as far as I know of. 
You could ask the contractor to fix it to open inwards. 
There is code that specifies how shower doors open - they all must open outwards, so when in the shower the door opens to the outside.

Comment: In residential construction there is no code requirements, except they can't swing out over a STEP.  You must have a landing...3' I think. In medical offices we like to swing bathroom doors out, so if someone has a medical problem and falls against the door, the door can still be opened.  Can you place a small table by the door (on the latch side).

Answer (score 9):

Unless the door opens directly into a set of stairs, doors can generally be installed to open in either direction.

A lot of times bathroom doors are installed to swing outward because the bathroom is quite small, and this orientation allows for more options when placing the fixtures in the bathroom. It also gives the illusion of the room being bigger.

Another fairly popular option is to install a pocket door, where the door slides sideways into the wall, rather than swinging inward or outward. This requires some additional work, as you are essentially installing a door twice as wide as a normal door, and you need to ensure you have the proper structure for it.